# Upgrade python3.8 to 3.10 in Ubuntu Docker image

Tags: python, docker, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04, python-3.10

I am using playwright base image

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright
```

Unfortunately, this comes with python3.8. I could either use python3.10 image and install playright on it, but it came with other complexities, so i chose to upgrade python on playright image to 3.10.

So far, my Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright

apt install -y software-properties-common && add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && apt update && apt install -y python3.10

RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.10 1
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 2
```

This works fine, but the problem is "How can i make python3.10" default version after setting up the alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to notice:

1. Python executable
2. Alternatives priority

### Executable

Running in the base image:

```
# which python
# which python3
/usr/bin/python3
# ls -l /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5230592 Jun 22 20:18 /usr/bin/python3.8
```

With the following Dockerfile (from the question);

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y python3.10

RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.10 1
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 2
```

`python` is now added and controlled by alternatives, but `python3` is untouched:

```
# ls -l /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Dec 16 04:10 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 13  2020 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5565184 Dec  7 01:12 /usr/bin/python3.10
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5230592 Jun 22 20:18 /usr/bin/python3.8
# ls -l /etc/alternatives/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Dec 16 04:10 /etc/alternatives/python -> /usr/bin/python3.8
```

### Priority

From alternative's [manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-alternatives.8.html):

> If the group is in automatic mode, and the newly added  alternatives'
> priority  is  higher  than  any  other  installed  alternatives for this group, the
> symlinks will be updated to point to the newly added alternatives.

This is numeric, so it's not that 1 is the winner and 2 is second-best, but rather 2 is higher than 1.

### Resolution

By changing both the executable form `python` to `python3`, and the priority so that `3.10` will be 2 and `3.8` will be 1 (as such):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y python3.10

RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python /usr/bin/python3.10 2
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python /usr/bin/python3.8 1
```

the default python version should be 3.10:

```
# which python
# which python3
# ls -l /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Dec 16 04:16 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5565184 Dec  7 01:12 /usr/bin/python3.10
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5230592 Jun 22 20:18 /usr/bin/python3.8
# ls -l /etc/alternatives/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Dec 16 04:16 /etc/alternatives/python -> /usr/bin/python3.10
# python3 --version
Python 3.10.9
```

Answer (score 1):

`python3` is simply a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/python3.8`. You can create a new link using the following command:

```bash
RUN ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python3
```

The `-f` (force) option overwrites the existing symlink with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

This Dockerfile should do the trick I think, though I'm not using `update-alternatives` so maybe not what you're looking for

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright


RUN apt update && apt install software-properties-common -y && add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt install python3.10 -y
RUN rm /usr/bin/python3 && ln -s /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python3
```

Basically we just delete the old symbolic link at `/usr/bin/python3` (which pointed the `/usr/bin/python3.8` binary) and create a new symbolic link at `/usr/bin/python3` (which points to the `/usr/bin/python3.10` binary that we just installed). Here's the output

```
➜ docker build . --tag test
[+] Building 14.7s (8/8) FINISHED                                                                                      
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 280B                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:latest                                              0.2s
 => CACHED [1/4] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright@sha256:adade3016b008d5a892fd228499eed34919b4d8128b9c04bd447eb  0.0s
 => [2/4] RUN apt update && apt install software-properties-common -y && add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa    9.5s
 => [3/4] RUN apt install python3.10 -y                                                                           4.6s
 => [4/4] RUN rm /usr/bin/python3 && ln -s /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python3                                   0.2s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                            0.2s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                           0.2s 
 => => writing image sha256:fba6bb8a4cbd26ec4be70fd9d9d7638bcd2139fed83fd6ca52ef52992d47d1dc                      0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/os                                                                             0.0s 
➜ docker run -it test      
root@0bbc072f22ce:/# which python3 
/usr/bin/python3
root@0bbc072f22ce:/# python3 --version 
Python 3.10.9
```